# Make custom visualization for ListView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, listadapter

I have a ScrollView which contains a lot of items. On the bottom of it I add a set of items from another Activity. I check the input ArrayList from another Activity and should to add proper count of checkbox to my Activity with ScrollView. I add items with the help of LinearLayout like that:

```
  public void addFiles()
        {

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<File>(this,
                    R.layout.new_order, R.id.fileCheck,
                    FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles) 
                    {
                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // creates view

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file, null);
                    view.setFocusable(false);
                    CheckBox textView = (CheckBox) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.fileCheck);
                    textView.setClickable(true);
                    textView.setText(FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles.get(position).getName().toString());
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    textView.setPadding(55, 0, 0, 0);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.file_icon, 0, 0, 0);
                    textView.setTextSize(16);
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);
                    textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                              checks.set(position, 1);
                            }
                            else{
                             checks.set(position, 0);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    return view;

                }
            };
}
```

I know that using ListView inside a ScrollView is not recomended but I tried to use LinearLayout for my aim, but it worked bad  - it couldn't updated properly. To display ListView in proper way I use such a class:

```
public class UtilityListView {
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        Log.i("ListAdapter count",Integer.toString(listAdapter.getCount()));
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

And use it after every data changing like that:

```
fileList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fileListView);
    fileList.setAdapter(adapter);
    UtilityListView.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(fileList);
```

But the height of the ListView is much bigger than quantity of items of the list...How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the ListView with footers and headers. All the attempts to use ListView inside the ScrollView were unworkable or unefficient. I did it like this:

```
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_listview, null);
    View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_listview, null);
    fileList.addHeaderView(header);
    fileList.addFooterView(footer);
    fileList.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);
    fileList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

All my items shows properly and I can get functionality, what I wanted.